# Save CheckBox in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, checkbox

I'm a Java beginner, and I'm having trouble saving checkbox's statuses, I need to create a list, and those options would be saved locally in the app itself.

The code works for only 1 checkbox, when I try to add another one, the second one does not work, it saves the same data as the first one.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
    final CheckBox checkBox2 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox2);

    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    final SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
    if (preferences.contains("checked") && preferences.getBoolean("checked", false) == true) {
        checkBox.setChecked(true);
    } else {
        checkBox.setChecked(false);

    }
    checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
            if (checkBox.isChecked()) {
                editor.putBoolean("checked", true);
                editor.apply();
            } else {
                editor.putBoolean("checked", false);
                editor.apply();
            }
        }
    });

    SharedPreferences preferences2 = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    final SharedPreferences.Editor editor2 = preferences2.edit();
    if (preferences2.contains("checked") && preferences2.getBoolean("checked", false) == true) {
        checkBox2.setChecked(true);
    } else {
        checkBox2.setChecked(false);

    }
    checkBox2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
            if (checkBox2.isChecked()) {
                editor2.putBoolean("checked", true);
                editor2.apply();
            } else {
                editor2.putBoolean("checked", false);
                editor2.apply();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Please Post your question in English here. If its spanish use [This](https://es.stackoverflow.com/)

Comment: Okay, just a moment.

Comment: This is english only site .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is keeping the same state because you are using the same shared preference for both checkboxes.
Also you can use only one editor

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

final CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
final CheckBox checkBox2 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox2);

SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
final SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
if (preferences.getBoolean("checkbox1", false) == true) {
    checkBox.setChecked(true);
} else {
    checkBox.setChecked(false);

}
checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
        if (checkBox.isChecked()) {
            editor.putBoolean("checkbox1", true);
            editor.apply();
        } else {
            editor.putBoolean("checkbox1", false);
            editor.apply();
        }
    }
});


if (preferences.getBoolean("checkbox2", false) == true) {
    checkBox2.setChecked(true);
} else {
    checkBox2.setChecked(false);

}
checkBox2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
        if (checkBox2.isChecked()) {
            editor.putBoolean("checkbox2", true);
            editor.apply();
        } else {
            editor.putBoolean("checkbox2", false);
            editor.apply();
        }
    }
});
```

}

Comment: Cool @CleideSilva ;)